# Prove that this set is open

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology

Given the set: $A = 
 \{(x,y)$ | $\cos(x+y) + \sin (x-y) < 1\}$, prove this set is open.

I define the function $f(x,y) = \cos(x+y) + \sin (x-y) < 1 $. It is continuous because it's sum of continuous.

I know the set of numbers contained in ($-\infty$ to $1$) is an open set, so since $f(x,y)$ is continuous, and I know the anti image of a continuous set is open I can conclude A is open.

But there's a thing I don't understand, imagine we define the set $A$ as: $\{(x,y)$ | $-2 \leq \cos(x+y) + \sin (x-y) < 1\}$ This set is also $A$. Here the image is contained in $[-2,1)$ so this set is not open and so my previous conclusion doesn't work.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As noted below, $[-2,1)$ is open in the subspace topology on $[-2,2]$ inherited from from the topology on $\mathbb R$. If you want to consider the function as a continuous surjective map onto its image, you need to give the image the subspace topology.

Answer (score 2):

The preimage under a continuous function of a set that is not open may also be open. So there is no contradiction, even though you cannot deduce what you want from the interval $[-2,1)$ without an additional discussion.